# DataTable select returns DBNull instead of string value

Tags: c#

In my code, Datatable has a value with integer type.
And when I use select method, the selected rows has a `{} DBNull` instead of `int`.

Firstly, thanks for answers. But those answers didn't understand my problem. 
So, I summarize my question again.

**1. my codes**

```
      dtGo.Rows.InsertAt(_drGo, 0);
      string _filter = "CODE = '" + _code + "'";
      DataRow[] _drArray = dtGo.Select(_filter);
```

**2. Visual Studio watch shows following**

my table dtGo has 101 columns. And when I select
          `_drArray = dtGo.select(_filter);`
          _drArray has 3 column values wrong and other columns has correct
          values.

Look below Visual Studio watch results.
dtGo watch shows...

```
      dtGo.Rows[0]  {Systems.Data.DataRow}  System.Data.DataRow
        ItemArray   {object[101]}           object[]
          [0]       "Go호가"                object{string}
          [1]       "001000"                object{string}
          [2]       "신라섬유"               object{string}
          [3]       151453                  object{int}
          ...
```

and _drArray watch shows...

```
      _drArray[0].ItemArray  {object[101]}  object[]
          [0]       "Go호가"                object{string}
          [1]       "001000"                object{string}
          [2]       "신라섬유"               object{string}
          [3]       {}                      object{System.DBNull}
```

Question Again. As you can see select method returned some rows. And except column 3, others have correct values of datatable. But column 3, dtGo has value but _drArray has DBNull.

Please help me how to fix this problem...
I added capture image.

dtGo watch:
[image: dtGo watch]

_drArray watch:
[image: _drArray watch]

Comment: in your screenshots the column 4 is working with int, look what is different between those columns

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the same row?

Comment: Please show us the query you are running to populate your `DataTable`, as well as a screenshot of the exact row that is showing `DBNull` as visible from your DB tooling (so we can see that it isn't actually `DBNull`). Please show us the value of `_code`.

Comment: Please also show us the values of `_drGo`.

Comment: What do you see if you type this into the Immediate window: `?_drArray[0] == _dtGo.Rows[0]` - I ask because you seem to have screenshotted a datatable called `dtGo호가` but your code refers to a table called `dtGo`

Comment: (When you use `.Select` to get an array of rows, they should be the same row objects as are in the table; it doesn't clone the row, make a bad job of copying some values, and then give you the duplicated different object, it just gives you another reference to the already existing object - the values should therefore be the same)

Answer (score 0):

For one thing you could change that `int` datatype to `Nullable<int>` or `int?` to handle this.

Comment: column 3 is created as typeof(int).

Comment: and among 101 columns, I have  some wrong values. They have type of int , string, double. So, I think, type of column is not problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I got a hint and solved from your answers.

The reason, I don't know. But I guess, because I used Insert(_drGo,0) instead of Add(_drGo).

I solved with this code.

```
DataRow[] _drArray = dtGo호가.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<string>(dtPrefGo호가 + "CODE") == _code)
    .ToArray();
```

this returns the same row order with datatable.
And dtGo.Select method returened row order from dtGo.Rows.Length to 0.

Thank you for all.....